# Programmatically calling blur disables the interaction with the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

My implementation have the following components on a modal screen.

- A form that will be used for searching.
- A table where the user will see the results

The user will be able to search and then scroll through the result list using the keyboard (using upward arrow or downward arrow).

When the user hits enter to search, I **blur** the focused field...
**When I blur the focused field the user loses the ability to scroll the browser window using upward arrow or downward arrow...**
In order to re-enable this default browser behavior the user should hit tab once on his keyboard...

**My Question is:**

> How can I programmatically re-able browser navigation?

PS.: The default browser navigation that I'm mentioning here is the behavior that happens when you hit upward or downward arrows on your keyboard.

Any help is really appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

---

Edited:

The following snippet of code describes my scenario
http://plnkr.co/edit/YCvfQt?p=preview

```
$scope.onSubmit = function() {
    $scope.dataSource.push({ name: $scope.personName });
    $('#personNameField').blur();
};
```

**Scenario(You should use only your keyboard to replicate):**

- In the Live Preview click on 'Open'  Using the keyboard you should
  write something and hit enter (don't click on screen)
- After clicking    on enter try scrolling through the list
- You will notice that it is    not possible (You are able to scroll
  again if you hit tab once)

**What I want to do here is enabling scrolling again after the user hits enter...**

*Please let me know if you need more context.*
Thank you

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Hi Teemu.
I'm editing my question and adding a replication of the scenario I'm describing...(in plunker)
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried giving the modal the focus?

Comment: Yes PeeHaa I was trying to solve this and I notice that. Thanks for help anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we only need to give focus on the main element on screen... In this case the modal....

For my example that would be:

```
$('#myModal').focus();
```

Thanks for the comments